# Extract value of inputs from a HTML document using PHP

Tags: php, html, search, full-text-search

I have 347 .htm files saved in a folder. Each file contains an HTML form (same structure in every file). Assume the HTML form in each file will have something like:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fhname" name="fhname" placeholder="User Name" value="Moe">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="shname" name="shname" placeholder="User Surname" value="Mahy">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Age" value="21-09-2000">

<select class="form-control" id="fhagency" name="fhagency" title="Select organsiation.">
    <option value="8">Google8</option>
    <option value="15">UKByte Ltd</option>
    <option value="17">Agency OneTwo</option>
</select>
```

I Managed to create a loop to get content of every file in the folder:

```
Foreach($filesText as $fileName=>$fileText){
    // I need help to search in the text for the value of each input
    //So I want to fillup this array

    $filesArray[$fileName]['fhname'] = $fname;
    $filesArray[$fileName]['shname'] = $shname;
    $filesArray[$fileName]['age'] = $age;
}
```

I need help to search in the text for the value of each variable, so:

- $fname  => will be the value of input with ID fname
- $shname  => will be the value of input with ID shname
- $age  => will be the value of select with ID age and so on...

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Hi @JordanS my question is in the code sorry... "I need help to search in the text for the value of each input"

Comment: What are you trying to do? What code have you tried, and how did the result differ from what you expected/intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [PHP DOMDocument: How do I get the value of an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217955/php-domdocument-how-do-i-get-the-value-of-an-input-field) and http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

```
$html = <<<EOD
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<body>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fhname" name="fhname" placeholder="User Name" value="Moe">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="shname" name="shname" placeholder="User Surname" value="Mahy">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Age" value="21-09-2000">

<select class="form-control" id="fhagency" name="fhagency" title="Select organsiation.">
    <option value="8">Google8</option>
    <option value="15">UKByte Ltd</option>
    <option value="17">Agency OneTwo</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
EOD;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$fhname = $dom->getElementById('fhname');
print $fhname->getAttribute('value');

=> Moe
```

This should get you pointed in the right direction.