# PHP DOMDocument: Get attribute value from id

Tags: php, dom

I would like to extract the value of the attribute "value" using the id tag.

My code:

```
<?php
 $url = 'http://turni.tt-contact.com/Default.aspx';
 $contents = htmlentities(file_get_contents($url));
 echo $contents."\n"; //html
 $dom = new DOMDocument;
 $dom->validateOnParse = true;
 $dom->loadHTML($contents);
 $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
 $data = $dom->getElementById("__VIEWSTATE");
 echo $data->nodeValue;
?>
```

I would like the attribute "value" -> "THIS":

```
   <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="THIS">
```

but the code returns only the html code.

What do I need to change?

Also by modifying it to:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$data = $xpath->query('//input[@id="__VIEWSTATE"]');
$node = $data->item(0);
echo $node->getAttribute('value');
```

I get this error:

```
  Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on null
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP DOMDocument: How do I get the value of an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217955/php-domdocument-how-do-i-get-the-value-of-an-input-field)

Comment: try $data->getAttribute('value')

Comment: getElementById  works not always. Find it ny xpath `//*[id=".$url."]`

Comment: I have already tried it but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
$data->getAttribute('value');
```

[PHP: DomElement->getAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327429/php-domelement-getattribute)

```
$attrs = array();
 for ($i = 0; $i < $data->attributes->length; ++$i){
   $node = $data->attributes->item($i);
   $attrs[$node->nodeName] = $node->nodeValue;
 }
 var_dump($attrs);
```

Comment: Not work -> Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on null in

Comment: Can you var_dump $data ? to show us the content
Maybe your variable is null

Comment: I have run: $dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($contents);

 $data = $dom->getElementById("__VIEWSTATE");
 
var_dump($data);  I get NULL

Comment: try to remove this line : `$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; `
And var_dump again

Comment: Output: https://pastebin.com/JJJDveQP                                                                I Get:
object(DOMNodeList)#3 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) }

Comment: But is the output that moves to "loadHTML" correct? 
I refer to this code:' htmlentities (file_get_contents ($url));'.

Comment: Ok.  "__VIEWSTATE" 
is there in the html code, why not?

Comment: Try to do it like that : `$contents = file_get_contents($url);`

Maybe the htmlentities overwrite something

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `htmlentities` as it will change the document's HTML tags from : `<html>` to `&lt;html&gt;`and your document won't be HTML anymore, just a plain text full of `&lt;` and `&gt;`, and so the methods to get nodes won't work.